# Can I get a variable of a type based on reflect.Type

Tags: go, reflection, type-conversion

How do I get convert `Value interface{}` variable, the original type of which is `T reflect.Type`, to a variable of `T`?

If this conversion could be done, I can replace `map[string]interface{}`+`switch value.(type)` with this method. I think this is more elegant.

For example

```
var a int = 1
aType := reflect.TypeOf(a)
type Value struct {
  T reflect.Type          // aType
  OriginValue interface{} // a
}
v := Value{aType, a}
// What should I do to get an integer from v.T and v.OriginValue?
```

Comment: Go is a statically typed language, types of variables must be known at compile time.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `reflect.Zero(reflect.ValueOf(V)).Interface().(T)` Where V and T are valid identifiers. see the doc https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero